# convert date and time in php

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

i just need date format like this "26 March 2015 - 11:59 pm"
how to get 'pm'in my code

```
$month_year=date('F Y');
$timestamp = strtotime("$month_year");
$result = date('t F Y - 11:59 a', $timestamp);
```

Comment: `$result = date('t F Y - 11:59 \p\m', $timestamp);`

Comment: 1. What should `26` be? the day or how many days the month has? 2. 11:59 isn't pm it's still before 12:00 so it's am?!

Comment: @Rizier123 its not 24hr format its 12hr

Comment: And from where comes the 26?

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry, its not included

Comment: @ShanuTThankachan What do you mean with not included?

Answer (score 0):

Just use DateTime like this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("h:i a", "11:59 pm");
echo $date->format("d F Y - h:i a");
```

Output:

```
09 March 2015 - 11:59 pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 $date = date("d F Y - h:m a");
```

Comment: if any answer is helpful to you then pls mark or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$month_year=date('F Y');
$timestamp = strtotime("$month_year");
echo $result = date('t F Y - H:i a', $timestamp);
```